# index.php being added after www. removed with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I know that it is simple to remove the index.php from a CodeIgniter URI with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`. My issue is occurring as a result of a couple of other rules in my .htaccess file.

My issue is when the user goes to www.mydomain.com/blog they are redirected to mydomain.com/index.php/blog, this does not occur when there is a trailing slash; www.mydomain.com/blog/ redirects correctly to mydomain.com/blog. I really do not want the index.php to be there. An additional side note is that ideally should the user enter index.php in the URL I would like them to be to a URL without.

My current .htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Protect CI system folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(application|system)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# Prevent rewriting URIs that exist: (-d directory -f files)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Remove index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

# Remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am relatively new to adjusting the .htaccess file; please let me know if there is anything in there that could be adjusted for optimisation, bad practice, etc, the majority of this has been created through wandering through Google!

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you set index file value in `config.php` to `''`?

Comment: Yes, the config file is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your rules matters. Try moving `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` to the bottom. Remember to also set the `$config['index_file']` in your `application/config/config.php`